# Sound suddenly broken on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, wubi, battery

I know there are lots of posts on this, but they don't seem to deal with my problem, so I'm going to start a new thread anyway.

I installed ubuntu 12.04 through wubi a few days ago, and everything was going perfectly fine until this morning when my sound suddenly stopped working without any warning. I have since found that changing between AC and battery power briefly restores sound for a few seconds. I've tried everything conventional from rebooting to checking sound settings (all fine), switching between digital output and speakers, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you have alsa mixer installed? check all outputs using it and make sure nothing is muted. is sound okay with windows?

Answer (score 0):

I do have alsamixer installed, all my outputs are using it, nothing is muted, and sound works fine in Windows. Rather strangely, the problem seems to occur when I click the restart button, either on Windows or Ubuntu, and the solution to it is to restart manually (by clicking the shut-down button). I have no why this happens, but at least there isn't much of a problem now.